# Thymeleaf Template (Spring MVC) unable to locate static resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

Problem with Thymeleaf Template locating the static files placed inside the root directory of the web app (including the CSS File below). I have added the relevant mapping (/resource) via addResourceHandlers() method (see config class below).

Maybe it has something to do with the recent switch to gradle (previously Maven). I may have overlooked something in build.gradle file?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{'/resources/stylesheets/test.css'}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Browser console output (on page load)

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/resources/stylesheets/test.css".
```

Thymeleaf

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!--Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{'/resources/stylesheets/test.css'}" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

</head>
...
</html>
```

Structure of .war directory

```
- root/
 --stylesheets/
   --- test.css 
 --images/
 --META-INF/
 --WEB-INF/ 
 --...
```

Config Class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/")
                            .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        }
...
}
```

Gradle build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.bmuschko.tomcat" version "2.2.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat-base'
version = '1.0'
group = 'com.project'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

war {
    baseName = '/'
    archiveName = "${project.name}.war"
}

war.doLast {
    ant.unzip(src: war.archivePath, dest: "$buildDir/$project.name")
}
sourceSets {
    main {
           java{
               srcDir 'src/main/java'
           }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            }
        }
    test {
          java {
             srcDir 'src/test/java'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/resources'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    modules {
            module("javassist:javassist") {
                replacedBy("org.javassist:javassist")
            }
        }

    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
        exclude group: "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler", module: "ecj"
    }
        ....               
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
         mavenLocal()
 }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'App',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}


test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'  
  testLogging {
        // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
        events 'started', 'passed'
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showStandardStreams = true
        showCauses = true
        showExceptions = true

        }
}
```

Comment: As I recall, `.addResourceLocations("/")` would try to find the resources in the classpath root, e.g. at `src/main/resources` instead of the war file root?

Comment: "/" does point to the deployment root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the class level RequestMapping inside the Controller was the cause. Had to Change it to method level (see below).

Wrong

```
@Controller("/register")
public class RegistrationController {    
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        return "...";
    }
```

Correct

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/register",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        return "...";
    }
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. With the solution you have provided, I already have request mapping at method level not at class level. This is still not working. I have Spring Boot Setup with thymeleaf template engine. CSS is still not resolved.

Comment: post the link to the question and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must locate your static resources into "src/main/webapp/resources/static" folder(not in "Java Resources/src/main/resources" ). (If you work on Eclipse, you may see "src" folder several times).
2. At MvcConfig.java you should add the static resource' link and accepted pattern as belove.

   ```
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/","/resources/");
   }
   ```
3. In your html page use the static resource link with thymleaf presentation.

```html
<link th:href="@{./resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css}"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"></link>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try appending the context path (~) like below.

The symbol "~" will be considered to be relative to the server root.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{'~/resources/stylesheets/test.css'}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You may locate the resource to the classpath like this:

`registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/")
                            .setCachePeriod(31556926);`

And I suggest you should add the directory name:

`registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/stylesheets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/stylesheets/")
                            .setCachePeriod(31556926);`

You do not need to modify other files any more.

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/resources/stylesheets/test.css}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Try without ' ' because you are making reference to a resource not a string. Also for making even better and just in case that not all your code is Thymeleaf you should do something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/stylesheets/test.css" th:href="@{/resources/stylesheets/test.css}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: @JamieWhite have you still had the same error? Or did the error change?